# Using a user defined NormFunction in FindFit or NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I would like to use a different norm instead of the 2-norm in `FindFit` (*Mathematica* 9). For example, instead of using

$$\sqrt{\sum (x_{\mathrm{model}} - x_{\mathrm{data}})^2}$$

I'd like to use

$$\sum \frac{x_{\mathrm{model}}}{x_{\mathrm{data}}}$$

I can tell `FindFit` to use a user-created function as the `NormFunction`. However, I am unsure of the syntax to use when defining $x_{\mathrm{model}}$. Can anyone point me to example code for using a user-defined `NormFunction` in `FindFit` or `NDSolve`?

Comment: It doesn't look too straightforward to do, since the norm functions always take $\text{model}-\text{data}$ as the argument. Worst comes to worst, you can use `NArgMin[]`/`FindArgMin[]` for your custom fitting.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. I will look into using 'NArgMin[]/FindArgMin[] for fitting, if I cannot code a user-defined normfunction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose your data is formatted as following:

```
data = Table[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1, .2}]
```

> {{x[0.], y[0.]}, {x[0.2], y[0.2]}, {x[0.4], y[0.4]}, {x[0.6], y[0.6]}, {x[0.8], y[0.8]}, {x[1.], y[1.]}}

You can use this symbolic "data" to peep into the `FindFit` to see what does the `NormFunction` take as its argument (as J.M. said (and [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html)), it's the residual):

```
Reap[
   FindFit[data, model[x, a, b], {a, b}, x,
     NormFunction -> (Sow[myNorm[#]] &),
     MaxIterations -> 1];
   ][[2, 1, 1]] // Quiet
```

> ```
> myNorm[{
>    model[x[0.], a, b] - y[0.],
>    model[x[0.2], a, b] - y[0.2],
>    model[x[0.4], a, b] - y[0.4],
>    model[x[0.6], a, b] - y[0.6],
>    model[x[0.8], a, b] - y[0.8],
>    model[x[1.], a, b] - y[1.]}]
> ```

So a custom `NormFunction` as the question specified can be realized as:

```
ydata = data[[All, 2]];

Reap[
   FindFit[data, model[x, a, b], {a, b}, x,
     NormFunction -> (Sow[
           Total[(# + ydata)/ydata ]
         ] &),
     MaxIterations -> 1];
   ][[2, 1, 1]] // Quiet
```

> $$\begin{split}
> &\frac{\text{model}(x(0.),a,b)}{y(0.)}+\frac{\text{model}(x(0.2),a,b)}{y(0.2)}+\frac{\text{model}(x(0.4),a,b)}{y(0.4)}\\
> +&\frac{\text{model}(x(0.6),a,b)}{y(0.6)}+\frac{\text{model}(x(0.8),a,b)}{y(0.8)}+\frac{\text{model}(x(1.),a,b)}{y(1.)}\\
> \end{split}$$

Comment: If you're going to do it that way, maybe one should cache `data[[All, 2]]` so that it is not being repeatedly evaluated... matter of fact, maybe just do `Total[1 + #/data[[All, 2]]] &`...

Comment: @J.M. Yes you're right. Well this is just a principle demonstration. But please see my edit.

Comment: @J.M. I keep `(# + ydata)/ydata` to emphasize the *x_model/x_data* structure OP asked.

Comment: @Silvia - thank you for the excellent explanation. I was able to implement this method into my fitting function, resulting in better fits of my model to my data.

Comment: @user7104 You're welcome.