# Fitting data to an expression

Tags: fitting, data

I am trying to fit the following data to an expression of the form shown in the code below but it doesn't seem to fit that well and I don't know why it isn't as this kind of data is routinely fit to such expressions. I would greatly appreciate any help or pointer on what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
data = {{3., 92.1445}, {3.1, 5.8997}, {3.2, -44.8126}, {3.3, -72.4833}, {3.4, -85.5145}, {3.5, -89.4885}, {3.6, -88.0608}, {3.7, -83.587}, {3.8, -77.5604}, {3.9, -70.9073}, {4., -64.1871}, {4.1, -57.7239}, {4.2, -51.6913}, {4.3, -46.1686}, {4.4, -41.1779}, {4.5, -36.7066}, {4.6, -32.7236}, {4.7, -29.1886}, {4.8, -26.059}, {4.9, -23.2921}, {5., -20.8469}, {5.1, -18.6868}, {5.2, -16.7775}, {5.3, -15.0885}, {5.4, -13.5933}, {5.5, -12.2677}, {5.6, -11.0904}, {5.7, -10.0433}, {5.8, -9.11012}, {5.9, -8.27735}, {6., -7.53272}, {6.1, -6.86538}, {6.2, -6.26625}, {6.3, -5.72797}, {6.4, -5.24286}, {6.5, -4.80566}, {6.6, -4.41044}, {6.7, -4.05333}, {6.8, -3.72946}, {6.9, -3.43566}, {7., -3.1688}, {7.1, -2.92572}, {7.2, -2.70467}, {7.3, -2.50286}, {7.4, -2.31854}, {7.5, -2.14996}, {7.6, -1.99571}, {7.7, -1.85441}, {7.8, -1.72465}, {7.9, -1.60573}, {8., -1.49591}, {8.1, -1.39518}, {8.2, -1.30215}, {8.3, -1.21645}, {8.4, -1.13741}, {8.5, -1.06396}, {8.6, -0.996458}, {8.7, -0.933501}, {8.8, -0.875442}, {8.9, -0.821579}, {9., -0.771564}, {9.1, -0.724697}, {9.2, -0.681676}, {9.3, -0.641105}, {9.4, -0.603681}, {9.5, -0.568705}, {9.6, -0.535828}, {9.7, -0.505399}, {9.8, -0.476719}, {9.9, -0.450137}, {10., -0.425305}, {10.1, -0.401871}, {10.2, -0.380186}, {10.3, -0.35955}, {10.4, -0.340314}, {10.5, -0.322126}, {10.6, -0.305338}, {10.7, -0.289249}, {10.8, -0.274209}, {10.9, -0.260219}, {11., -0.246928}, {11.1, -0.234337}, {11.2, -0.222445}, {11.3, -0.211603}, {11.4, -0.20111}, {11.5, -0.190967}, {11.6, -0.181874}, {11.7, -0.17278}, {11.8, -0.164386}, {11.9, -0.156691}, {12., -0.149346}, {12.1, -0.142001}, {12.2, -0.135356}, {12.3, -0.12906}, {12.4, -0.123114}, {12.5, -0.117518}, {12.6, -0.111922}, {12.7, -0.106676}, {12.8, -0.102129}, {12.9, -0.0972324}, {13., -0.0930354}, {13.1, -0.0888383}, {13.2, -0.0846412}, {13.3, -0.0811436}, {13.4, -0.0772963}, {13.5, -0.0741485}, {13.6, -0.0706509}, {13.7, -0.0675031}, {13.8, -0.064705}, {13.9, -0.061907}, {14., -0.0591089}, {14.1, -0.0566606}, {14.2, -0.0542123}, {14.3, -0.051764}, {14.4, -0.0496655}, {14.5, -0.047567}, {14.6, -0.0454684}, {14.7, -0.0433699}, {14.8, -0.0416211}, {14.9, -0.0398723}, {15., -0.0381235}, {15.1, -0.0363747}, {15.2, -0.0349757}, {15.3, -0.0335767}, {15.4, -0.0321776}, {15.5, -0.0307786}, {15.6, -0.0293796}, {15.7, -0.0279806}, {15.8, -0.0269313}, {15.9, -0.025882}, {16., -0.024483}, {16.1, -0.0234337}, {16.2, -0.0223844}, {16.3, -0.0216849}, {16.4, -0.0206357}, {16.5, -0.0195864}, {16.6, -0.0188869}, {16.7, -0.0181874}, {16.8, -0.0171381}, {16.9, -0.0164386}, {17., -0.0157391}, {17.1, -0.0150396}, {17.2, -0.01434}, {17.3, -0.0136405}, {17.4, -0.012941}, {17.5, -0.0125913}, {17.6, -0.0118917}, {17.7, -0.0111922}, {17.8, -0.0108425}, {17.9, -0.010143}, {18., -0.0097932}, {18.1, -0.00909368}, {18.2, -0.00874393}, {18.3, -0.00839417}, {18.4, -0.00769465}, {18.5, -0.0073449}, {18.6, -0.00699514}, {18.7, -0.00664538}, {18.8, -0.00629563}, {18.9, -0.00594587}, {19., -0.00559611}, {19.1, -0.00524636}, {19.2, -0.0048966}, {19.3, -0.00454684}, {19.4, -0.00419708}, {19.5, -0.00384733}, {19.6, -0.00349757}, {19.7, -0.00349757}, {19.8, -0.00314781}, {19.9, -0.00279806}, {20., -0.0024483}, {20.1, -0.0024483}, {20.2, -0.00209854}, {20.3, -0.00174879}, {20.4, -0.00174879}, {20.5, -0.00139903}, {20.6, -0.00139903}, {20.7, -0.00104927}, {20.8, -0.000699514}, {20.9, -0.000699514}, {21., -0.000349757}, {21.1, -0.000349757}}
```

The model expression is:

```
vdc[RR_] := 
  Module[{R = RR, \[Alpha]0 = 16.36606, \[Alpha]1 = 
     0.70172, \[Beta]0 = 17.19338, \[Beta]1 = 0.09574},
   A[num1_Integer] := \[Alpha]0 num1^-\[Alpha]1;
   B[num2_Integer] := \[Beta]0 Exp[-\[Beta]1*num2];
   \[Rho] = 5.5 + 1.25 R0;
   R0 = 6.46;
   \[Chi][R_, 
     n_Integer] := (1 - Exp[-(A[n]*R/\[Rho]) - (B[n]*R^2/\[Rho]^2)])^n;
   v[R_] = Sum[\[Chi][R, n]*Subscript[CC, n]/R^n, {n, 6, 10, 2}]
   ];
vtotal[R_] := (a* Exp[-b * R]) - vdc[R]
```

and here is my trial code

````
dataplot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{2., 8.0}, {-400.0, 700}}, ImageSize -> Large];
fit = FindFit[data, 
  vtotal[R], {Subscript[CC, 6], Subscript[CC, 8], Subscript[CC, 10], 
   a, b}, R, Method -> NMinimize, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity];

Show[{dataplot, Plot[vtotal[R] /. fit, {R, 2., 8.0}]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"R", 
   "Potential Energy,\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-1\)]\)"}]
```
````

Comment: Have a look at `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: How important is to use "a model expression" for your fit? If it is not, you can try [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html).

Comment: Anton Antonov the model if very important in this problem.

Comment: Your data are not asymptotically consistent with you model: the model goes as $1/R^6$ for large $R$ (verify with `Asymptotic[vtotal[R], R -> ∞]`) but your data do not: try `ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[1]]^6*#[[2]]} & /@ data]` (does not approach an asymptote for large $R$). Maybe your long-range dispersion forces are not calculated correctly.

Comment: Hi Roman, the model is a double many body expansion (DMBE) and converges a 1/R$^6$ as you correctly predict. This data is a slice of a 3D potential fit to an Ab Initio data calculated at CCSD(T)-F12b/CBS. I think the data is accurate enough and I have edited it to exclude the highly repulsive region and one can as well exclude points beyond R=21

Comment: Fitting potentials is a very tricky business that requires specific experience. I recommend you ask this question question on a Physical Chemistry forum, not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in your original dataset you had retained the large values associated with $R<3$, then @DanielHuber 's approach is a good one (which is one way to account for varying precision of the observations).

But with your modified dataset with $R\geq 3$, there is less need for weighting.  However, because the data and model structure induces high correlations among the parameter estimators and because of the wildly different scales of the parameter values, having good starting values for the parameters is essential.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, vtotal[R], 
  {{a, 4.75 10^8}, {b, 4.8}, {Subscript[CC, 6], 900000}, {Subscript[CC, 8], -10^8},
   {Subscript[CC, 10], 2.6 10^9}}, R];
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{3, 8}, {-100, 100}}], 
 Plot[nlm[R], {R, 3, 8}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

One can see the high correlations large standard errors for most of the parameter estimators.

Using `NonlinearModelFit` allows one to obtain diagnostic statistics which allows checks on the appropriateness of the fit.  You can't get that with `FindFit`.  (Although `FindFit` now has the `NormFunction` which is great for robust regression models.)

And to confess:  I didn't use magic or hallucinogenic drugs to come up with the starting values.  The model being fit is essentially a linear model with the exception of the `Exp[-b R]` term.  So I just tried a bunch of values for `b`, used `LinearModelFit` on the remaining parameters, and looked at the best fit.  Then I plugged those values into `NonlinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your data:

[image]

If you try a least square fit to this data, MMA mainly tries to fit the leftmost end because that is where the large errors are. Therefore you must in some way tell MMA, that the errors at the left end are less important. That is you need a weighted fit. In FindFit you may specify a norm function, that the actual error to be minimized calculates. So, we give some function (you may try different functions), that weigh the data at at the left end less:

```
fit = FindFit[data, 
   vtotal[R], {Subscript[CC, 6], Subscript[CC, 8], Subscript[CC, 10], 
    a, b}, R, NormFunction -> (Norm[#^-0.4 #] &)];
Plot[vtotal[R] /. fit, {R, 2., 8.0}, Epilog -> Point[data], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You hit the nail on the head about the large response values determining the solution with least squares.  But even with `MaxIterations -> 5000` I don't get convergence with your code.  Also, what does `#^-0.4 #` mean?  Does it mean `#^0.6` ?

Comment: The region of interest is in the range R >=3 thus I have edited the data to remove the high energy data points (where R < 3)

Comment: @JimB  I wrote Norm[ #^-0.4 # ] for didactical reasons to separate the weight from the error.

Comment: @DanielHuber.  Sorry that 4-syllable word is too much for me.  Is there something in the documentation that tells me what `Norm[ #^-0.4 # ]` means if it doesn't mean `Norm[#^0.6]` ?

Comment: @JimB do not worry, it is the same.

Comment: Sorry to be so thick.  But running it both ways gives wildly different parameter estimates.

Comment: @JimB Of course it should giver the same. However, this was adapted to the original data, that are no more available. With the new data #^-0.4 #  gives nonsensical results with tremendous numbers. It looks like some cancellation error, but I can not tell what exactly is happening.

Comment: This is not a "gotcha".  I really want to understand.  The original dataset is still available.  Here are the "missing" values:  `{{2., 15858.5}, {2.1, 10855.9}, {2.2, 7346.87}, {2.3, 4908.57}, {2.4,  3229.68}, {2.5, 2084.4}, {2.6, 1310.79}, {2.7, 793.984}, {2.8, 453.257}, {2.9, 232.31}}`. The two different `Norm` functions give different results and using `Norm[#^-0.4 #]` does not converge after 5,000 iterations (`MaxIterations -> 5000`) on *Mathematica* 12.1, Windows 10.

Comment: It looks like if I study the answer at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24016/using-a-user-defined-normfunction-in-findfit-or-ndsolve/24017#24017, it will answer all of my questions and give a roadmap to construct just about any other norm.

Comment: @JimB Hi Jim, I checked it and got exactly the same result. For the check I used the following: NormFunction -> (Norm[Print[#]; #^0.6] & Note that you will get a large output. It would be really strange if #^0.6 and #^-0.4 # would not be equal.